# Submitted for Review back to a Draft page

Tags: post-status

I would like to allow a WordPress contributor to change a draft page Submitted for Review back to a draft page without giving the contributor the capability to publish pages. I have tried without success:

```
function post_pending ( $new_status, $old_status, $page ) {
   if ( $old_status == 'draft'  &&  $new_status != 'pending' ) {
      edit_post_link();
   }
}
if ( current_user_can( 'contributor' ) ) {
    add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'post_pending', 10, 3 );
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just wanted to pop in and say that as of Wordpress 4.9 [this solution still works.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/210293/132916)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a permissions issue - contributors can (by default) change a post from pending to draft. To test, submit a post for review, then "quick edit" it - you'll see that you're able to change the status back to draft.

The issue is that the "save as draft" button in the UI is hidden once a post is submitted for review - let's "restore" it:

```
function wpse_210259_revert_to_draft_button() {
    global $post;

    $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );

    if ( $post->post_status === 'pending' && ! current_user_can( $post_type->cap->publish_posts ) ) {
        printf(
            /**
             * Since there are no hooks where the original "Save Draft" button
             * appears, use CSS positioning to "fake" it to give the user a
             * consistent UI.
             */
            '<button style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;" class="button" type="submit" name="post_status" value="draft">%s</button>',
            __( 'Save as Draft' )
        );
    }
}

add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'wpse_210259_revert_to_draft_button' );
```

Comment: Than you so much for your help. I am just seeing this now. I will test this tomorrow. Of note, contributer on my site will not have access to quick edit.  Again. thank you so much.